# What is the composition of relations like this? With no transitive relations between them?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Given

> $ R_1 = \{(1,2),(5,3)\}\quad\quad R_2 = \{(6,4),(5,7)\}$
>
> What is $R_2 \circ R_1$?

Because in my understanding, using the example

> $ R_3 = \{(1,2),(3,4)\} \quad\quad R_4 = \{ (2,5),(6,7)\}$
>
> Then $R_4\circ R_3 = \{(1,5)\}.\;$ Am I correct?

So given that case, if $R_2 \circ   R_1 = (a,b),\;a$ comes from $R_1$, right? While $b$ comes from $R_2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have by definition (assembled from your example)
\[ R_2 \circ R_1 = \{(a,b) \mid \exists c : (a,c) \in R_1, (c,b) \in R_2\} \]
In the $R_4 \circ R_3$ example $(1,5) \in R_4 \circ R_3$ as we can "plug in" $2$ in the middle where $(1,2) \in R_3$, $(2,5) \in R_4$.

If there is no "matching" pair from $R_1$ and $R_2$ as it is in your case, there is no $(a,b)$ fulfilling the condition for being a member of $R_2 \circ R_1$, we have by definition $R_2 \circ R_1 = \emptyset$.