# How to intuitively think about composition of relations?

Tags: relations, function-and-relation-composition

Examples:

1. $A \cap B$

   elements that are in both $A$ and $B$
2. $A \cup B$

   elements that are in either $A$ or $B$
3. $R \subset A\times B$

   coordinates where the first coordinate is an element of $A$, and the second is an element of $B$
4. $S \subset B\times C$

   coordinates where the first coordinate is an element of $B$, and the second is an element of $C$
5. $R^{-1}$

   coordinates of $R$, but the first and second coordinate are flipped
6. $S\circ R$

Is the final example something like this?:
coordinates where the first coordinate is the first coordinate of a coordinate in $R$, and the second coordinate is the second coordinate in a coordinate in $S$, AND the second coordinate in $R$, and the first coordinate in $S$ are both in the same set

Comment: Your title asks for intuition but your body seems you only want to rephrase the definition of $S\circ R,$ as you did for $R\subset A\times B$ and $R^{-1}$ (btw, for each, better begin with "[set of] ordered pairs" than "coordinates"). The correct definition of $S\circ R$ ([also denoted by $R;S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Definition)) is: "the set of ordered pairs $(x,z)$ for which there exists a $y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in S$". Don't be afraid of using letters like $x,y,z.$ It makes things clearer than convoluted simple english sentences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notation for the composition of functions and relations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329073/notation-for-the-composition-of-functions-and-relations)

Comment: The grandfather is the father of the father... and similar.

Answer (score 0):

For intuition, you could think of $S \circ R$ as consisting of the ordered pairs that come from merging an ordered pair $(a, b) \in R \subset A \times B$ with an ordered pair $(b, c) \in S \subset B \times C$ to get an ordered pair $(a, c) \in A \times C$. (Note that the second coordinate of the pair from $R$ is the same as the first coordinate of the pair from $S$.)